# VS2010 - A project with that name is already opened in the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The problem started after installing RiaServices Toolkit Dec 2010 (I guess).

If I unload the project and reload it again, I get this message, even on an empty project (any type - no changes made to the project file).

```
Unloaded ~\ConsoleTestApp.Cmd\ConsoleTestApp.Cmd.csproj
Loading ~\ConsoleTestApp.Cmd\ConsoleTestApp.Cmd.csproj
error : A project with that name is already opened in the solution.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had a similar problem in VS2010, but not related to the RiaService toolkit.

My solution was to **delete the .suo file in the solution directory**.

Comment: Make sure to first close the solution, *then* delete the .suo file.

Comment: Same problem and solution on VS2012 RC.

Comment: Helped me out again, this time over 3 years later!!

Comment: @Rob: looking forward to seeing you here again at some point this year :P

Comment: Good lord, you'll never guess what's happened @demoncodemonkey!

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (Workaround 2):

This problem is caused by a bug in AnkhSVN (issue 625) that relates to path casing.

**Workaround 1**

Disable AnkhSVN SCC Provider in Visual Studio (Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection) or uninstall AnkhSVN.

**Workaround 2**

In New Project dialog in Location text box use path in subversion normalized form. The normalized form is drive letter in upper case and all directories cased exactly as on disk. That is for example `"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects"` instead of `"c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects"`.

[From:](http://sharpsetup.eu/documentation/html/89aa2503-3aee-4c11-aa9c-e485f0b0ef6e.htm)

Comment: Was a problem with AnkhSVN here, too. The latest version of AnkhSVN doesn't have this problem though.

Comment: I'm actually using the latest version... and have the same problem.

Comment: Workaround #2 fixed this problem for me (I wanted to keep SVN, so did not want to try #1).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem when trying to add an existing project.

I went to the Ankh SVN homepage here and downloaded the newest daily build here: http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/daily After installing the freshest version, the problem was still there.

Therefore I paid better attention. The preselected folder when trying to add an existing project pointed to the network share of my own computer. Selecting the same proejct on a local harddisk fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using AnkhSVN in VS2010.

My solution was to move the project I was trying to load into the path that was under SVN management.  Originally I was trying to load the project from outside of the "trunk" path.

Example:  my other loaded projects were located in the folder path like this:

```
\\srv\documents\vs projects\svntrunk\project*
```

But the project I was trying to load was in a different path, (outside of the SVN trunk)

```
\\srv\documents\some other folder\projectToLoad\
```

I copied the folder `\projectToLoad\` and put it under

```
\\srv\documents\vs projects\svntrunk\*
```

After which, I was able to load the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, when I modified a Visual Studio Project File (*.csproj) from outside Visual Studio (so in another program I have just called Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Load(MyProject.csproj) while this project was currently opened in VS. I've found the solution, and I described it here, on [codeyourself](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127054330/http://codeyourself.net/a-project-with-that-name-is-already-opened-in-the-solution/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error occurs when using in field "Look in" specific meaning. 
After i set the option "Entire Solution" problem disappeared.

PS: sorry for bad english

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, and it was resolved when I restarted VS in administrator mode.